# Ошибка NoneType is not iterable в цикле

Tags: python, list, null

В цикле выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Пытался исправить так:

```
if None in listUsers:
    listUsers.remove(None)
for user in listUsers:
    adj[user] = getFriends(user)
```

Ошибка остаётся прежней, но уже в строке с условием. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В listUser ничего нет, судя по всему.  Пусто.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте заменить весь код из вопроса на следующий:

```
adj = {user:getFriends(user) for user in listUsers if user} if listUsers else {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно у вас в прежнем коде случилось, что `listUsers` is `None`.

Чтобы проверить это, напишите на консоли Питон:

```
listUsers = None
None in listUsers
```

и на выводе вы получите

> ```
> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
> ```

Значит, что вы нужны или применить тест перед вашим кодом (`if listUsers is not None:`) или использовать другой подход (например как в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/848023/233990)).